# How to find whether the type of the element in the list is TextBox or CheckBox in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, razor, checkbox, textbox

My code is like this:

```
<div class="features">
    <ul class="featuresTest">
        <li id='chklist1'><input id='Checkbox1' type='checkbox' checked /></li>
        <li id='chklist2'><input id='features2' type='textbox' /></li>
        <li id='chklist3'><input id='Checkbox1' type='checkbox' checked /></li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

In my Code, these Checkboxes and textboxes are dynamically generated using Jquery.

Now I am using `$.each()` to find which list(li tag) inside the unordered(ul tag) list contains textbox and checkbox.

This search has to be done on the basis of id of the li tag inside the ul tag.

```
  $("#textbutton").click(function () {


                $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetFeaturePkId")', function (featurepkid) {

                    var featurespkid = featurepkid;
                    $.each(featurepkid, function (k,v) {
                        if ($(".featuresTest > li.chklist" + v + "").has('input[type="textbox"]')) {
                            alert("textbox");
                        }
                        else  {
                            alert("checkbox");
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

on the above code the featurepkid returns 1 to 20.

I tried this,but failed.

Please kindly advise me on that issue.

Comment: `$('ul.featuresTest li input[type=checkbox]')
$('ul.featuresTest li input[type=textbox]')`

Comment: Don't use duplicate ID's

Comment: I am using each() to search through a loop. For eg.) I have written like this... $.each(featurepkid, function (k,v) {});.....In this,featurepkid is a primary key returned from database.......Inside the each function i wrote like this for searching textbox and checkbox based on the value of featurepkid.....In the each() function I wrote this**if ($(".featuresischeckedul > li.chklist" + v + "").has('input[type="textbox"]')) {
                        alert("textbox");
                    }**

Comment: I want to search through the list based on the id for the li tag generated dynamicaly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you edited your question I find problem in you javascript code.

In you `if` you have `$(".featuresTest > li.chklist" + v + "").has('input[type="textbox"]')` .. and that return array of elements ... if jQuery selector don't find anyting, it return empty array - `[]`.

So statement compare true/false ... but when he get empty array - `[]` he transform it as `[].toString()` and this return empty string ... and that is `true`.

So to answer question you shoud replace

```
if ($(".featuresTest > li.chklist" + v + "").has('input[type="textbox"]'))
```

to

```
if ($(".featuresTest > li#chklist" + v).has('input[type="textbox"]').length)
```

`.length` will return count of elements in array ... so when jQuery selector dont find anything it return 0 and thats `false` instead of `true` because of empty array.

Comment: @Shaddow...Thank you...It's working when the checkbox and textboxes are given in the lists statically. but if the lists are dynamically generated, it's not working. How can I test the dynamically generated testbox and checkbox in the list...Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

To get the `li` tag, you can do this :

```
var liCheck = $('.featuresTest li').filter(function(){
    return $(this).children('[type=checkbox]').length;
})
var liText = $('.featuresTest li').filter(function(){
    return $(this).children('[type=textbox]').length;
})
```

Comment: Gagnon...I want to search through the lists as it was generated dynamically....I did this,but failed.... **if ($("#chklist" + v + "").children().has('input[type="textbox"]'))**....Please help me

Comment: instead of : `$("#chklist" + v + "").children().has('input[type="textbox"]')` try `$("#chklist" + v).children('input[type="textbox"]').length`

Comment: I tried that, but it's not working...Thanks for your reply...Please advise me on that issue....I also trying to solve this.....

Answer (score 0):

You can check the tagName property

```
$(".featuresTest > li").each(function () {
    console.log($(this).children('input').tagName);
});
```

you can also use the `.has()` function of jQuery

```
$(".featuresTest > li").has('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
       // iterate over li's with checkboxes
});
```

and

```
$(".featuresTest > li").has('input[type="textbox"]').each(function () {
       // iterate over li's with textbox
});
```

EDIT:

In response of your comment, I'd say try using children instead of has and check for length

```
$.each(featurepkid, function (k, v) {
    var $elem = $(".featuresTest > li#chklist" + v);
    if ($elem.children('input[type="textbox"]').length) {
        alert("textbox");
    } else {
        alert("checkbox");
    }
});
```

Comment: @UmairP Thanks for the quick response.....I want to search through the id of the li tag in the ul.....Please help me...

Comment: if the chklist1 of the li tag contains textbox then it should alert as textbox......else checkbox.......likewise I want to search for the whole li tag....i.e.) if the li tag with id of chklist2 contains checkbox then it should return checkbox...

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `:has` selector:

```
$('.featuresTest > li:has(input[type=checkbox]):has(input[type=textbox])')
```

**EDIT:** If you want find `li` inside `ul` which contains one of this (checkbox/textbox) `input` types you can use [Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
$('.featuresTest > li:has(input[type=checkbox]), .featuresTest > li:has(input[type=textbox])')
```

Now you can apply `.each()` method to find ID:

```
.each(function() {
    console.log( $(this).attr('id') );
});
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/2zMjw/)

Comment: This would find no elements, since it requires the presence of both types

Comment: So I dont understand question - he is looking for li inside ul contains checkbox and textbox

Comment: The OP wants to find which `li` contains each type. I agree, though, it's hard to work out what (s)he wants. Hence why I haven't given an answer...

Comment: So he wants checkbox **or** textbox?

Comment: I want to search for the li tag with the "id" chklist1,and I am using each() to loop through the id value as chklist2,chklist3,..to find whether it contains textbox or checkbox...Thanks in advance...Please advise me on that issue

Comment: @user2309770 - You want find `li#chklist1` that conintas `input[type=checkbox]` or `input[type=textbox]` ?

Comment: I want to find li#chklist1...here id="chklist" will be dynamically generated as it loops through each()...

Comment: I want to find input[type=textbox]

Comment: You shoud reformulate your question because its not clear enough

Comment: ` $("#textbutton").click(function () {
           

            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetFeaturePkId")', function (featurepkid) {
               
                var featurespkid = featurepkid;
                $.each(featurepkid, function (k,v) {
                    if ($("chklist" + v + "").has('input[type="textbox"]')) {
                        alert("textbox");
                    }
                    else if ($("chklist" + v + "").has('input[type="checkbox"]')) {
                        alert("checkbox");
                    }
                });
            });
        });`

Comment: In the above code in the if condition i need to do the logic...Please help me....Thanks in advance

Comment: 1st of all instead of `$("chklist" + v + "")` shoud be `$("#chklist" + v)`

Comment: @Shaddow I tried that,but it didn't succeed....I also did this.....** if ($("#chklist" + v + "").children().has('input[type="textbox"]'))**, but this too faied....